# ESXI VM Controls in Guacamole

Tags: java, angularjs, esxi, guacamole

Sorry for the novice question, but I'm stuck and new to this framework.

Currently I'm attempting to integrate some VM Controls into the Guacamole Interface. I have a java class that will be doing the sending of the commands to the ESXI server in order to power on/off VM's and take snapshots of them/revert to previous snapshots.
Currently I have added menu options in the clientController.js/client.html files so that these operations can be performed. The problem that I'm running into is that I'm not sure where to implement the java class in order to be able to launch the functions when a client clicks on the menu item.
Also if I'm going about this in the wrong way I'm open to other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following:

Every message send from the browser to the GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet in guacamole-common starts with either "connect" "read" or "write". That's how it makes normal VNC and RDP possible. The servlet get's a message starting with one of those three commands and the servlet will call the right function. If I understand correctly you would not really need the guacamole daemon in this case am I right? You could just add a new connect keyword for your implementation and make sure that on get's called by adding a few `if` statements in `GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet.handleTunnelRequest()`.

You should also make sure  that the initial connect message is correct on the client's side.